# Mysterious P/Invoke threading deadlock (Mono only?)

Tags: c#, multithreading, mono, pinvoke, deadlock

I have this strange problem with a P/Invoke call to a C library that I have no control of.
Basically I have a thread where a native method (`GetData`) is called continuously and a second native method (wrapped in a managed method) (`SetSetting`) that is called once in a while on the main thread.
Those two methods may never be called at the same time or I get an error, so I wrap it into a `lock`block.
Now the strange thing is that if I call `SetSetting` the program hangs in the `GetData`method as soon as as the `SetSetting` method reaches the `lock` keyword.
To make it a bit more clear, some code:

```
object lobj = new object();  //The lock object

public void SetSetting()    //The managed method calling the second native method
{
    lock(lobj)
    {
        NativeSetSetting();    //native method (irrelevant as it hangs before it's called)
    }
}

public void ContinuousGetData()    //Method that is running in a different thread
{
    while(DoStuff == true)
    {
        lock(lobj)
        {
            GetData();    //native method that hangs
        }
        //here is some other code happening that gives enough time to
        //not constantly block the lock from this thread
        //(it's not relevant to the problem, I tried that)
    }
}
```

So the process looks like this:

- Start new thread with `ContinuousGetData` method
- Call `SetSetting` method
- Execution reaches the `lock` keyword in the `SetSetting` method
- Program hangs and if I press pause in the debug window, it points to the native 'GetData` method

Same thing happens with other ways of synchronizing the thread (e.g. ResetEvents).
This got me thinking that the native call is executed on the main thread (where the `SetSetting`is waiting for the native call to finish) and it can't execute because it's waiting for itself.

Some more information:

- The problem only occurs on Mono for Mac (.Net on Windows works)
- The native library is different on Mac and Windows (but I don't know how much)
- It always hangs in the same native call (there are more than one, but only this one makes a PTP call over USB to a camera)

Is this a possible behavior of Mono on Mac or do you think it's a different handling in the platform specific native library?
Is there anything else I can do to synchronize threads safely?

I'm happy about any help

Comment: "This got me thinking that the native call is executed on the main thread (where the SetSettingis waiting for the native call to finish) and it can't execute because it's waiting for itself." => Could you do an experiment where SetSetting was explicitly called, async, on a seperate named thread to test this possibility?

Comment: And when the 'lock' happens how does the CPU utilization look?

Comment: @ tolanj Didn't think of that and it really does work. If the lock is on a separate thread it works fine. The CPU fires up to 100% if the program hangs.

Comment: If the native code hangs then all bets are off and nothing you posted here is relevant to the problem.  Of course your program will hang as well.  You'll need to tackle the real problem, find out what is wrong with GetData().

Comment: @HansPassant it is relevant because the native code works just fine as long as I don't hit the lock keyword. Then and only then I have a problem

Comment: Try getting a native stack trace for all threads (from a terminal do: `lldb -p <PID>` and then `bt all` once lldb attaches to the process)

Comment: @JohannesB it therefore _does_ sound like the P/Invoke is happening on the main thread, can you provide more details of the actual definition of GetData?

Comment: Also do you pass anything in to GetData?

Comment: And are you _sure_ your GetData 'wrapper' is really running on a seperate thread and not just in a seperate task / whatever?